# Words instead of numbers in a co-occurrence matrix with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, networkx

I have this code. It reads a list of sentences, and then uses sklearn's CountVectorizer to compute word co-occurrences.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
data = ['this is a sentence', 'this was a monkey', 'all this is nice']

count_model = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,1)) # default unigram model
X = count_model.fit_transform(data)
Xc = (X.T * X) # this is co-occurrence matrix in sparse csr format
Xc.setdiag(0) # sometimes you want to fill same word cooccurence to 0
matrix_dense = Xc.todense() # matrix in dense format

import networkx as nx
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(matrix_dense)
```

If I do `G.edges(data=True)`, it outputs this:

```
   [(0, 1, {'weight': 1}),
 (0, 3, {'weight': 1}),
 (0, 5, {'weight': 1}),
 (1, 3, {'weight': 1}),
 (1, 4, {'weight': 1}),
 (1, 5, {'weight': 2})
```

and so on. How can I get words instead of numbers as source, target?

**EDIT:**

This is a:

```
labels = count:model.get_feature_names() # get the word labels

G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(matrix_dense) # create graph

for node, label in zip(G.nodes(), labels): # add labels to the graph
    G.node[node]['label'] = label
```

Comment: You can use `. get_feature_names` on your `CountVectorizer` object to get a list of the feature-names at the corresponding index.

Comment: Thanks. Now, with the feature names as a list, how do I get then as labels in the graph?

Comment: Um, so its a *map*, number -> string, so presumably, you can simply iterate over the list being returned form `.edges` and replace whatever you want accordingly...

Comment: Thanks! I edited above with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With networkx you can replace one set of with another set of nodes.  This is with [`relabel_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html).

Here is the example from the documentation.  It creates a 3 node graph and then creates a copy of that graph with the new node names.  You can also do directly to `G` by setting the optional argument `copy` to `False` in the function call.

```
G = nx.path_graph(3)
sorted(G)
> [0, 1, 2]
mapping = {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
sorted(H)
> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Nice. But in this case I guess one also has to somehow create the `mapping` dictionary based on `.get_feature_names()` if it is too long to type manually.

Comment: In fact, I'd recommend against typing it manually even if it is short, because having the code able to generate the mapping makes it more easily reusable when things change.